# Tuning MySQL RDS which has WriteIOPS unstabilities

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-web-services, innodb, temp-tables

We are having troubles tuning MySQL 5.6 on AWS, and are looking for pointers to solve some performance issues.

We used to have dedicated servers and we could configure them how we like.
Our application uses a lot of temporary tables and we had no performance issue on that regard.
Until we switched to AWS RDS instance.
Now, many slow queries show up in the logs and it slows down the whole application.

Previously we worked with MySQL 5.4 and now it's 5.6.
Looking through the docs, we discovered some changes regarding the temporary tables default format.
It is InnoDB by default, and we set it back to MYISAM like we are used to and constated improvements on that regard.

**first aspect:**

Also, our DB is quite large and we have hundreds of simultaneous access to our application, and some tables require real-time computation. Join and Unions are used in that cases.
When developing the application (with MySQL 5.4), we found that splitting the larger queries into 2 or more steps and using intermediate tables, the over-whole performance improved.
`Explain` showed file sort and temporary file so we could get rid of those with temporary tables.

Is splitting queries into temporary tables really a good idea?
*Edit* We know conditions about the implicit conversion of MEMORY temporary tables to disk.

Another thing we are not sure is what makes query using temporary files?
We know using correct indexes is one way to go (correct order usage in where clause, correct usage of `order by` etc…), but is there anything else we could do?

**second aspect:**

Regarding some settings we are using, we have some hundred Mb for `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` so we hoped that our temporary tables could hold in memory.

We also found articles describing to look at ReadIOPS and WriteIOPS.
The reads are stable and low, but the writes are showing unstable and high numbers.
Here is a graph:

[image: Left: writes, Right: reads]
The values on the vertical axis are operations/sec.

How can we interpret those numbers?

One thing to know about our application, is that every user action is logged into one big logs table. But it should be once per page load.

**third aspect:**

<del>How far can we go with those settings so temporary tables can be used in Memory?

For instance, we read some articles explaining they set few Gb of `max_heap_table_size` on a dedicated MySQL server with about 12Gb of ram. (sounded like 80% or so)

Is that really something we can try? (Are same settings applicable on RDS?)
Also, can we set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` at the same value as well?</del>
**Note** I can't find there article where I found that info, but I might have confused some parameter names. I'll edit the question if I find the source again.

The server settings are very different from what we used to have (the new servers on AWS are not set by us) and many settings values have been increased, and some decreased.
We fear it's not a good thing…
Here are the some noticable changes:

- innodb_buffer_pool_size (increased *6)
- innodb_log_buffer_size (decreased /4)
- innodb_additional_mem_pool_size (decreased /4)
- sort_buffer_size (decreased /2)
- myisam_sort_buffer_size (increased *1279) (we have only innoDB tables, do we need to touch that?)
- read_buffer_size (increased *2)
- join_buffer_size (decreased /4)
- read_rnd_buffer_size (increased *4)
- tmp_table_size + max_heap_table_size (increased *8)

Some changes look weird to us (like `myisam_sort_buffer_size`), we think that using the same settings would have been better in the first place.
Can we have some pointers on those variables? (Sorry, we can't provide the exact numbers)
Also, is there a good article we could read that sums up a good balance between all those parameters?

Because we are concerned about the temporary tables not fitting in memory, I made that query to see what percentage of queries are actually written to disk:

```
select 
  tmp_tables
  ,tmp_tables_disk
  ,round( (tmp_tables_disk / tmp_tables) * 100, 2 ) as to_disk_percent
from
  (select variable_value as tmp_tables from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where variable_name = 'Created_tmp_tables') as s1
  ,(select variable_value as tmp_tables_disk from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS where variable_name = 
'Created_tmp_disk_tables') as s2
```

The result is 10~12% (depending on the instance). Is that high?

## TL;DR

I tried to add as many details to the question as possible about the current situation, I hope it's not more confusing that anything...

The issues are about writes.
Is there a way to diagnose what causes so many writes? (maybe linked to temporary tables?)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.4 never existed.  Perhaps MariaDB 5.4?

Temp tables, even if seemingly not hurting performance, are a clue that things could be improved.

- Do you have `TEXT` columns that you don't need to fetch.  (This can force an in-memory temp table to turn into on-disk.)
- Do you have `TEXT` columns that could be a smaller `VARCHAR`?  (Same reason.)
- Do you understand that `INDEX(a,b)` *may* be better than `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)`?  ("composite" index)
- The buffer_pool is very important for performance.  Did the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` change?  How much data do/did you have?  How much RAM do/did you have.

In general, "you cannot tune your way out of a performance problem".

Is this a Data Warehouse application?  Building and maintaining Summary tables is often a huge performance boost for DW "reports".

MyISAM only has table locking.  This leads to blocking, which leads to all sorts of performance problems, especially slowing down queries.  I'm surprised that InnoDB was slower for you.  MyISAM is a dead end.  By the time you get to 8.0, there will be even stronger reasons to switch.

Let's see one of the slow queries that benefited from splitting up.  There are several techniques for making complex queries run faster (at least in InnoDB).

The order of `ANDed` things in `WHERE` does *not* matter.  It *does* matter in composite indexes.

Changing `tmp_table_size` rarely helps or hurts.  It should, however, be kept under 1% of RAM -- this is to avoid running out of RAM.  Swapping is the *worst* thing to happen.

Graphs - what are the Y-axis units?  Where did the graphs come from?  They look useless.

"Gb of `max_heap_table_size` on a dedicated MySQL server with about 12Gb of ram. (sounded like 80% or so)" -- Check that article again.  I recommend 120M for that setting on that machine.

When exclusively using MyISAM on a 12GB machine, `key_buffer_size` should be about 2400M and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be 0.

When exclusively using InnoDB on a 12GB machine, `key_buffer_size` should be about 20M and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be 8G.  Did you change those when you tested InnoDB?

`innodb_additional_mem_pool_size` -- Unused, and eventually removed.

`myisam_sort_buffer_size` -- 250M on a 12G machine.  If using only InnoDB, the setting can be ignored since that buffer won't be used.

As for the *6 and /4 -- I need to see the actual sizes to judge anything.

"sums up a good balance between all those parameters" -- Two things:

- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory
- Leave the rest at their defaults.

For more tuning advice, plus Slowlog advice, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: thank you for your great answer. I might have misunderstood the article about `heap_memory`, I'll look for it, let's ignore it for now.
I'll look for the details you asked and I'll edit the question.
Thank you for the links and your input about the settings, I'll have a look when back at work.

Comment: I have added the vertical axis unit explanation in the question. Those are operations per second.  
The main question is why so many writes? Are there some variables to check and see what causes so many writes?

Comment: I double checked, MySQL 5.4 was released:
http://mysql.localhost.net.ar/downloads/mysql/5.4.html
This is what we had until AWS. (other companies are in charge of the services, we just do development)

Comment: @CedricSimon - I stand corrected.  Perhaps 5.4 was released only by Sun on Solaris?

Comment: We ran it on RedHat EL5, the rpms are on the page I provided the link of.